# how to display the json data in secondactivity, when button clicks in mainactivity

Tags: android-intent, getjson

I can display the json array to main activity,but i want to pass it to second activity.i followed this article
 http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly send json object.
Like on first activity :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("jObject", jObject.toString());
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("JSONData", bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

On second activity :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras().getBundle("JSONData");
String jObject = extras.getString("jObject");
```